# StoreKit framework 2 questions

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, storekit

Just getting started with store kit framework. I have 2 questions:

1) Is there a way to find out all the purchased items by the current user? (get a list of ids)
2) Is there a way to purchase ALL items? Or do I have to prompt the user for each and every one?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to find out purchased items by calling [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];

Then

```
-(void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions{

for (SKPaymentTransaction * transaction in transactions) {
    switch (transaction.transactionState)
    {
        case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:   break;
   case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
```

// get info about item from transaction.originalTransaction.payment.productIdentifier

```
            [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
            break;


        case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:     break;

        case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing:      break;

        default:
              break;
}
}
```

}

2) Even if You can tell user that it is possible to buy all items by one click. User will be asked to purchase each item separately.

Answer (score 0):

1. `[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];`
2. If those are different IAP in iTunes you have to prompt the user for each and everyone. However if you want you can create a single IAP in iTunes (e.g. com.abc.packOfTen) and on purchasing it you can provide 10 items to user.